# Visual Studio Code align function parameters on multiple lines

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, indentation, code-formatting, auto-indent

If a Javascript (or Typescript) function signature has multiple lines of arguments (can happen easily in Typescript, with longer type names), Visual Studio Code indents like this after I hit `return`:

[image]

I would prefer it line up the arguments, like this:

[image]
[image]

Is there a setting somewhere to do this automatically, so I don't have to manually indent the code?

(I also want to do this for function *calls*.)

Comment: +1 Seems like such a trivial and popular feature that VS Code Team missed? VS 2015/2017 retain the alignment preference from first line.

Comment: What approach did you take? Coming here after 3 years... :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably check out some linters if they can do it for you. Search in Extensions for plugins such as eslint or tslint.